# Unable to mock open, even when using the example from the documentation

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, mocking

I've copied and pasted the following code directly from the Python [mock docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open):

```
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open

with patch('__main__.open', mock_open(read_data='bibble')) as m:
    with open('foo') as h:
        result = h.read()

m.assert_called_once_with('foo')
assert result == 'bibble'
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: <module '__main__' from 'path/to/file'> does not have the attribute 'open'
```

Given that this is the example given in the documentation, I'm not sure where else to turn. I'm running Python 3.4.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

`open` is a builtin, so I needed to patch `builtins.open`, not `__main__.open`.

Skipped over this info in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `__main__` is the module name given by default when you run a script.

Paste the code in a python file and call it.