# Using unittest.mock's patch in same module, getting "does not have the attribute" when patching via "__main__.imported_obj"

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, python-unittest.mock

I have what should've been a simple task, and it has stumped me for a while.  I am trying to `patch` an object imported into the current module.

Per the answers to [Mock patching from/import statement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351382/mock-patching-from-import-statement-in-python)

I should just be able to `patch("__main__.imported_obj")`.  However, this isn't working for me.  Please see my below minimal repro (I am running the tests via `pytest`):

**Minimal Repro**

This is run using Python 3.8.6.

```py
from random import random
from unittest.mock import patch

import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def foo():
    with patch("__main__.random"):
        return

def test(foo) -> None:
    pass
```

When I run this code using PyCharm, I get an `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: <module '__main__' from '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py'> does not have the attribute 'random'
```

Furthermore, when I enter debugger mode in the line before the `with patch`, I see the attribute `__main__` is not defined.  I am not sure if it needs to be defined for `patch` to work its magic.

NOTE: I know I can use `patch.object` and it becomes much easier.  However, I am trying to figure out how to use `patch` in this question.

**Research**

[Unable to mock open, even when using the example from the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155048/unable-to-mock-open-even-when-using-the-example-from-the-documentation)

This question is related because it's both a similar error message and use case.  Their solution was to use `builtins` instead of `__main__`, but that's because they were trying to `patch` a built-in function (`open`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assuming that the module the test is running in is `__main__`, but that would only be the case if it were called via `main`. This is usually the case if you are using `unittest`. With pytest, the tests live in the module they are defined in.

You have to patch the current module, the name of which is accessible via `__name__`, instead of assuming a specific module name:

```
from random import random
from unittest.mock import patch

import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def foo():
    with patch(__name__ + ".random"):
        yield
```